# In angular google chart how to set columns if they are dynamic

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization

I have a incoming data where data series is dynamic
Ex:
Date:   Error Type:   Count:
01/01   E1            10
01/01   E2            15
01/02   E1            12
01/02   E3            20

I need to plot a chart Date Vs Count for each Error Types. In the above example E2 is not there in 01/02 and E3 is not in 01/01.

In this example, I can't extract and set columns for google charts as I will not know how many types are there till I go over complete list.

Is there any way, I can handle dynamic series?

Answer (score 0):

in google charts, series' are determined by columns, e.g.

Label, Series 1, Series 2, Series 3

recommend setting up data table as follows...

with columns for each error type
(you could cycle through the data and create columns for each error type)

the value for each error type column would be the count

columns --> `Date, E1, E2, E3`

then when loading the rows...

`01/01, 10, 15, null`
`01/02, 12, null, 20`

Comment: I am going to give a try, my concern is I will have to go over thousands of records to get headers and again comparing each time when loading data. Also I am not sure how can I compare while populating data to find how whether that particular column value exists or not.

Comment: you can add columns, while loading the data, just need to check column labels before adding new column -- any rows added before the column is added will default to null -- how is the data generated to begin with, what is the source?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try it. Data is coming as JSON from rest service.

Comment: ideally, you would want to produce json on the server, and send in the format google accepts -- as in the first example listed under the [DataTable Constructor method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#constructor_1)...

Comment: I changed JSON response to send data to null one also' I could not get UI working without that data.

Comment: don't follow, do you still need help?